# SPSS Syntax - IF statements with multiple AND commands

Tags: if-statement, syntax, spss

I am trying to recode a variable with an IF statement with 3 x AND conditions within it.
When I run the syntax it doesn't present any errors but the variable has not changed.

Example of Syntax:

```
 IF (((Variable_a =0) AND (Variable_b=0)) AND (Variable_c >0)) Variable_d=9999.
```

I've tried various combinations of ()s but no joy.

All values in each variable are numerical

Any suggestions of how to overcome this?

EDIT - added an 'execute' command to the end of the code. Unfortunately it still doesn't appear to be work.

Comment: This should work without ANY ()s. Missing values in either of the variables could break the logic. If there are no missing values, please edit your post to add a couple of rows of data as example to demonstrate the expected, and the actual results.

Comment: Brackets don't even matter here, since you only have AND operator here. But here is a long shot: Are you executing the transformations ? Or does the SPSS Data window say "Transformations pending" in the lower right side (where it also says "Processor ready")

Comment: Thanks for the comments folks. 
@eli-k the data does have several missing answers in it. Any suggestions on a work around? I've run a similar code in the past with 2 x 'AND' and several missing answers in the dataset and they seem to have worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @horace_vr it was saying transformations pending, so I've added an execute, and re-run the syntax . Still doesn't appear to have worked when I look at the descriptive statistics.
It's good to know there's doesn't appear to be anything totally obvious going on here!!

Comment: Thanks for your help both - I've managed to sort it out. I tried a few different things so can't pinpoint exactly what it is that was wrong, but added the execute command, removed the brackets, recreated the variables to make sure spelling/values were correct. One or a combination of those has helped so thankyou :)